# nettcpbinding how add service reference correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service, nettcpbinding

please help me. I create service whith netTcpBinding and security `mode="Message"`        message `clientCredentialType="UserName"`, this is my config

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://topaznet.hq.eximb.com/RS/Svc/RS.svc"
    binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBindingEndpoint"
    contract="RSClient.IRS" name="wsHttpBindingEndpoint" />
</client>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="CredoServiceBehavior" name="CredoService.Credo">
    <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" name="netTcpBindingEndpoint"
      contract="CredoService.ICredo" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange" endpointConfiguration="" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost/CredoService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>

<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="netTcpBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
  </bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CredoServiceBehavior">
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="CredoService.Common.CustomUserNameValidator, CredoService"/>
        <serviceCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="91797E67B20D0853A90CA8E228AF460A382ED94B" />
        <windowsAuthentication allowAnonymousLogons="true"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="2147483647" maxConcurrentSessions="2147483647" maxConcurrentInstances="2147483647"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Service hosted in IIS and work fine.
I create new windows forms project and click Add Service Reference, visual studio genetate for my config :

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="netTcpBindingEndpoint1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                    enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/CredoService/Credo.svc"
            binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpBindingEndpoint"
            contract="CredoClient.ICredo" name="netTcpBindingEndpoint">
            <identity>
                <servicePrincipalName value="host/home" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

In this web config:

```
                    <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                </security>
```

but in my service

```
  <security mode="Message">
    <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
  </security>
```

if i change this client dont work and throw exception.
How can i fix this?

Comment: This just a code dump. "Dont work" and "throw exception" are meaningless. _What_ does not work? What exception is thrown? Where is the exception thrown? You have to help us help you.

Comment: In your <client> section: bindingConfiguration="netTcpBindingEndpoint" <- is that a typo here or you've actually written that? There's no such bindingConfiguration according to your code dump. It should be netTcpBindingEndpoint1.

Comment: @Vadim did my solution work for you??? Can you please either accept the answer or post a comment letting us know how it went?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just spotted another issue with your code. Your service isn't picking the binding!

```
<endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" name="netTcpBindingEndpoint"
  contract="CredoService.ICredo" />
```

needs to be

```
<endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpBinding" name="netTcpBindingEndpoint" contract="CredoService.ICredo" />
```

in your `<services><service><endpoint>` section.

That would explain why VS is going with default NetTcpBinding instead of your options.